# Why do we use the word "thereof"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Firstly I am not very good in English, so pardon me, is my question sounds too silly.

- Why we use "thereof"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is [a formal way of referring to something just mentioned](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thereof).

> *formal*
>
> of the thing just mentioned;
>   of that: *the member state or a part thereof*.

I like this example: "This chair is suited to your life or lack thereof."

Here *thereof* refers to the life you may or may not have, and the chair will suit you in either case.

Comment: +1. *Thereof* can usually be replaced by *of it*, *of one*, *of any* or something similar: *This chair is suited to your life or lack of one*.

Comment: @psmears,  "thereof" is still longer than that of which it replaces... Isn't it like quite a pointless term seriously besides showing *faux-authority*?

Comment: @mplungjan, What do you think of the above comment?

Answer (score 4):

It reflects the fact that *its* is a relatively modern word.  Until about 1550, *his* was used for both modern *his* and modern *its*.  When that use of *his* became obsolete, it was replaced by *thereof*.  On the Liberty Bell, this verse from the King James Bible appears:  "Proclaim liberty throughout all the land unto all the inhabitants thereof."  In modern language we would say "all its inhabitants", but the word *its* does not appear in original editions of the King James Bible.  Because of this use of *thereof*, it survived until modern times in highly formal, legal, and religious language and parodies of them ("parodies thereof", I might say).

Comment: Why would ‘its’ have anything to do with ‘thereof’? The former is a possessive form of an anaphoric pronoun, the latter a combination of a demonstrative pronoun and a preposition. ‘Thereof’ is not equivalent to ‘its’, but to ‘of it’ or ‘of that’.

Comment: "Its" and "of it" are semantic equivalents.

Comment: In some contexts, yes; in others not. “Whereof one cannot speak, thereof one must be silent” cannot be rephrased with _its_, for example. It’s not really accurate to say that _his_ as a possessive of _it_ was **replaced by** _thereof_ in the 16th century, either: it wasn’t a one-to-one switch (both _it_, _of it_, and _therefore_ were used where previously _his_ had been more common), and _therefore_ had been in use as a possessive circumlocution of _it_ for at least a couple of centuries by that time.

Comment: A good example that was solved by your great answer @JohnCowan: "a trial that hath been used time out of mind in this nation, and seems to have been coeval with the first civil government thereof". "Thereof" here relates to "nation", and it could be replaced by "**its** first civil government".

Answer (score 1):

Here's *another* example usage of the word:

Instead of:

> The truth of the matter will be determined by the quality and quantity **of** the evidence.

..The writer may opt for:

> The truth of the matter will be determined by the evidence (the quality and quantity **thereof**).

..But I agree with the other folks that the word can be replaced by "of it":

> The truth of the matter will be determined by the evidence (the quality and quantity **of it**).